# how to import point cloud data in matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm a complete rookie Matlab user - requiring an answer to this question in the simplest terms possible! I've been looking through the help documentation and can't really find the right place to start.

For a project, I have scanned a sample with a laser scanner, and received a point cloud of the sample, in a single text file, with rows of x,y, and z co-ordinates (Roughly 400,000 points). I would like to import this text file into Matlab, and create a model of the sample.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you had a look at Matlab's `textscan` function? http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html

Comment: Make a cut down copy of your original file while you figure out how best to tackle this problem.  Then experiment with the Matlab function `uiimport`.  Read the documentation and follow the links from `uiimport` to other pages as your understanding develops.

Answer (score 3):

If the textfile just contains the coordinates in rows, you can use the `load` command.

```
load filename.txt;
data = filename;
```

than I would use `scatter3` to plot the data.

```
scatter3( data(:,1) , data(:,2) , data(:,3) );
```

If the textfile is more complex and it's not convenient to "prepare" it, you can use the suggested filescan command. But I guess it is much slower.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what the textfile looks like I can't guarantee succes, but try this:

1. Navigate inside matlab to the folder containing the file
2. Right click on the file
3. Choose *Import*

Here you will find several options to import your file. This works for most files that are easily imported.

If desirable you can tell matlab to generate a script for the import (checkbox in this import wizard), then you can even do it programatically.